# Trailblazer Rails React - How can I call 'concep' from .jsx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, trailblazer

Inside a .JSX, I want to call

```
<%= concept('thing/cell',@operations).(:form) %>
```

, in order to display in the same JSX the view-form.How can I do it? I think it's not possible to use Rail inside a JSX.
Thanks!

```
var x = React.createClass({
   ....,


  render: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-default trigger-button" onClick={this.displayBox}>Reply</button> 
            </div>

        )
    },
displayBox: function () {
     $(".trigger-button").addClass("hidden")
     .... // Code for rendering the form 
}
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmm given that your file ends with .erb , ruby code will get executed before sending the JSX code to the client, now the client is responsible for compiling JSX into plain javascript. in short : I think you can put Ruby code inside JSX

Comment: You might want to check out react-rb and skip cells altogether.